# Remove Font-Awesome MaxCDN Link & Load Locally

Tags: functions, fonts

MaxCDN is slowing down my site so I want to load font-awesome locally but I can't seem to write the correct function to remove it.

```
function remove_unwanted_css(){
wp_dequeue_style(‘font-awesome’, ‘https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css’);
}
add_filter(‘wp_print_styles’, ‘remove_unwanted_css’);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must find the name of the enqueued stylesheet in your theme and use it to dequeue a style - [wp_dequeue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style). URL is unnecessary.

Example:

```
function remove_unwanted_css() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'font-awesome' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_unwanted_css', 100 );
```

Or another solution [wp_deregister_style/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_style/):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_default_stylesheet', 20 );
function remove_default_stylesheet() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'font-awesome' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'font-awesome' );

    wp_register_style( 'new-font-awesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/new.css', false, '1.0.0' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new-font-awesome' );
}
```